# micronaut-data and composite key mapping

Tags: kotlin, micronaut-data

I have an entity with a composite key

```
@Entity
data class Page(
  @EmbeddedId
  val pageId : PageId,
  ...
)

@Embeddable
data class PageId (
  @Column(name = "id")
  val id: UUID,
  @Column(name = "is_published")
  val isPublished: Boolean
)
```

But I need to respect the existing column names in the db table, which are 'id' and 'is_published'
But querying the db with a JDBCRepository I get the error:

> SQL Error executing Query: ERROR: column page_.page_id_published does
>   not exist

Is there any way that I can map the columns correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try and error led me to the answer, somehow Micronaut does not like a Boolean to be named 'isPublished', when I rename it to 'published' it works fine:

```
data class PageId (
    @MappedProperty(value  = "id")
    val id: UUID,
    @MappedProperty(value = "is_published")
    val published: Boolean)
```